# How to convert text symbols like ‰^“]€”õONŠ back to Japanese so I can google translate it to English? (Script?)

Tags: dictionary, character, cjk

I am working with Mitsubishi PLC files that were originally commented in Japanese but then opened on English-only computers which converted the Japanese symbols to incomprehensible latin keyboard symbol combinations such as ‰^“]€”õONŠm”F(‘€ì”Õ1).

Being able to understand these comments would greatly enhance my ability to analyze and modify these files as I am required to do so for my work. If I could translate these back to Japanese symbols (I do have the Japanese language pack installed on my windows laptop), I could then translate these with Google Translate, which I know is not perfect, but is a lot better than #@$$##&^.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be done? I figure that Windows must have interpreted the original characters somehow, and there may be a way to interpret them back to the original symbols.

I am thinking of trying to do some kind of character translation using a script in Python or Powershell or VBA (maybe I can create a map in Excel...)

Any ideas?
I can export these comments into CSV files so easy to get to and manipulate if I can figure out how....
This is an ongoing problem for me so I am willing to put some time into a solution.

I tried re-opening the oldest version of the files, in my computer with the Japanese language pack installed and no luck.

Comment: Try running the text through https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html and then through https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html (UTF-16 big endian)

Comment: This worked awesomely! Thank you jluims! I just had to modify the character encodings to "Windows-1252" and "Shift JIS (Japanese)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your text through an [ascii to hex converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html) and then through a [hex to ascii converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) in order to change the encoding without your system settings being in the way.